# Posting a chat reply does not clear the pending notification badge

Tags: bug, chat, notifications

I am quite often in the [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) chat room and subscribing  to notifications from the bots from time to time.

Using this feature I experienced that when I get mentioned by the bot, then review the thing I got notified about and reply to the bot (or other users, the result is the same), the notification "bubble" (see the picture below) doesn't go away and the title stays `(*) SOBotics | ...` until you click the bubble.
[image]

This gets very annoying, especially when you are off-chat for a while and then come back and have to click away that "bubble" repeatedly.

Comment: Posting a message should clear this, (it does for me), so this is a bug.

Comment: That was quick ^^

Comment: I am quick. :-D

Comment: Do you have other SO chat windows open?

Comment: @Catija No, just on. Also I'm only in the SOBotics chatroom.

Comment: Ah. Hmmm. I've definitely had the bubble get stuck but I usually attribute it to having lots of chat rooms open coupled with the computer going to sleep in the interim. Refreshing the page and then clicking on the alert bubble (or sending another message) usually clears it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime this seems to got fixed, the bubble goes now away for me.